# How can I manipulate docx at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, docx, openxml-sdk

My task is to take docx file, manipulate it, fill placeholders and return it to a user. I have C# project that consists of several webservices that makes it work.

By now I have done it following way:

1. Take docx file
2. Open it via OpenXML SDK
3. Apply some algorithms
4. Fill placeholders
5. Return

All of this is happening in C# code. Now I have an idea to move all alghortims to database. The reason is when something change there will be no need to deploy application to webserver. I would like to take docx template, take some script from database and apply to it.

Do you know how can I accomplish this? One way is to use XSLT but I don't like this idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is [SC-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) and [IronPython](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/) which can be used to accomplish the "runtime" part. Both are well integrated with .net environment.